# Adding User Agent to Safari

Tags: safari, user-agent

Good day,

Dear community, could somebody tell me, is that possible to add User Agent Safari 10 to Safari 12.0.1? And if it possible, be so kind, tell me how.

[image]

Comment: What is under the "other" link?

Comment: 'Other...' gives a type-your-own-string dialog